# Are questions about how to further golf a program on-topic here?

Tags: discussion

I have a simple algorithm that I'm using for code golf, and I'm hoping to find ways to golf it further. The algorithm is somewhat golfed in Python already, and works flawlessly. I asked on meta.codegolf.SE if a question about it would be on topic there, and per the [discussion](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/632/7849), the community thinks it would be too localized for that site.

Someone suggested that I post the code here, but I'm asking on meta first to make sure it's on topic for this site.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Code golfing isn't really what we do. We emphasize making code readable, which is really the opposite of code golfing. Its just not really in the right spirit for us.

If the community agrees, I'll edit the FAQ to make this clear.

Comment: Good point. I wasn't sure it would fit here, either, but I figure at the least, asking helps everyone here clarify the FAQ.